# C++ implicit copy constructor member variable copy ordering

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, copy-constructor

Just want to double check: the C++ standard guarantees that member variables are copied in order of declaration by the **implicit** copy constructor, right? In the following example, `a` gets copied before `b`, right? (Assume that both `A` and `B` have non-trivial copy constructors and it's important for correctness that `a` gets copied before `b` gets copied.)

```
struct Foo {
  A a;
  B b;
};
```

I'm interested if it's guaranteed by the standard or is it implementation dependent?

Comment: In fact, the order of initialization of bases and members is exactly defined and identical (with direct members in declaration order) for all possible kinds of class initialization: user-defined constructor, explicitly defaulted constructor, implicitly declared constructor, inherited constructor, or aggregate initialization.

Comment: Or maybe not for some inherited constructors? That might be a weird case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the initialization order is guaranteed for [implicitly-defined copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-defined_copy_constructor):

> For non-union class types (class and struct), the constructor performs
>   full member-wise copy of the object's bases and non-static members, in
>   their initialization order, using direct initialization.

And the initialization order of [data members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order) is the order of their declaration.

> 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition.

From the standard, [[class.copy.ctor]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.ctor#14)

(emphasis mine)

> The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class X
>   performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members. [ Note:
>   Default member initializers of non-static data members are ignored.
>   See also the example in [class.base.init]. — end note ] **The order of
>   initialization is the same as the order of initialization of bases and
>   members in a user-defined constructor** (see [[class.base.init]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.base.init)).

and [[class.base.init]/13.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.base.init#13.3)

> Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were
>   declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the
>   [*mem-initializers*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.base.init#nt:mem-initializer)).